# send image in pixels using .net webservice

Tags: c#, .net

i wrote a webservice for send image in pixels form. it is working fine but when we give large amount of data in parameter it do not take full data. it take limited data or small image.
is this parameter limit? or How i give large data in parameter?

Here is my code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument testuploadimage(string image)
    {

        XmlDocument login = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = login.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
        login.AppendChild(dec);
        XmlElement root = login.CreateElement("CreateUser");
        login.AppendChild(root);

        try
        {

                string actFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                string s = image.Replace(" ", string.Empty);


                string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
                //       string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".png";

                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image.Replace(" ","+"));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                // MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
                // Convert byte[] to Image
                //  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                Image image2 = Image.FromStream(ms);
                image2.Save(actFolder + imgname);


                XmlElement root1 = login.CreateElement("uploaded");
                root1.InnerText = "true";
                root.AppendChild(root1);
                XmlElement root2 = login.CreateElement("path");
                root2.InnerText = "http://Myserver/HeritageWebServices/Images/" + imgname;
                root.AppendChild(root2);

                return login;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrLogMgr.LogErrorMessage(string.Format("{0}{1}", "testuploadimage() for the image :",
                                                       image), "testUploadimage Inputs",
                                                        ERRORSOURCE.CSASERVICE);
                XmlDocument cd = new XmlDocument();
                cd.LoadXml("<Message>" + ex + "</Message>");



                return cd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things

Try to change the maxRequestLength on the web.config file.

i see that you are using base64 to send the image, you could try to compress the bytearray before convert it to base64, to reduce the image or try to convert to a more compressed image type (ej: bmp to png).

regards

Comment: Hii Thanks 4 reply..i changed my maxRequestLength on the web.config.
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="600000"/>
but still parameter is not taking whole data..it takes limited amount of pixels.

Comment: do you have check the length of the string?

Comment: Try with maxMessageLength on the service configuration, an example of use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx

Comment: Hi..no,i am still working on it..now i install wse3.0 and try to solve this issue..